# Ansible - How to sequentially execute playbook for each host

Tags: ansible

I am using ansible to script a deployment for an API.  I would like this to work sequentially through each host in my inventory file so that I can fully deploy to one machine at a time.

With the out box behaviour, each task in my playbook is executed for each host in the inventory file before moving on to the next task.

How can I change this behaviour to execute all tasks for a host before starting on the next host? Ideally I would like to only have one playbook.

Thanks

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Have a closer look at [Rolling Updates](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html):

What you are searching for is

```
- hosts: webservers
  serial: 1
  tasks:
    - name: ...
```

Comment: ProfHase85, Thank you for the answer, but could you show an example, how to pass 'serial' value via command-line arguments? According to this issue https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/1767 it should be possible, but it's hard to find a good sample of that.

Comment: It has actually nothing to do with the question, just a standard usage of variables. Here is a gist for it:
https://gist.github.com/profhase/57af3e715ec7faf5bf34d84299228591

On the last line there is the example call for it

Answer (score 3):

Using the --forks=1 specify number of parallel processes to use (default=5)

Comment: This has a different effect. If you have tasks A and B, and hosts 1 and 2, `--forks=1` results in A1 A2 B1 B2, whereas OP is asking for A1 B1 A2 B2 (all tasks applied to host 1, then all tasks applied to host B).

Answer (score -1):

Strategy enable to parallel tasks in a per host basis.  See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_strategies.html

There are  3 strategies: linear (the default), serial and free (quickest)

```
- hosts: all
  strategy: free
  tasks:
    ...
```